# Missing toolbar Visual Studio 2015

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

im getting crazy, i don't see the toolbar in code on visual studio 2015, that toolbar that for example let you select when a botton lost focus,clicked etc

do anyone got the same problem?

thanks guys,
and have a great day
José Lopes

Comment: Problem solved installing visual studio 2013 instead of 2015 but still really strange

Comment: Does it count as solving the problem if you just installed a different program?

Comment: don't really know but i guess so, for other users with the same problem they will find the anwser here :)

Comment: @ze21038 that's no solution at all. What will you do when by some mistake you make 2013's toolbar vanish? VS 2015 does *not* have a toolbar bug. You hid the toolbar somehow. Reset the settings or right click on the menu bar and customize the visible toolbars

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos The navigation bar does seem to hide without user intervention. It was hidden by default when I installed VS2015. On a co-worker's machine, it was visible but then decided to be hidden without his ever touching the options.

Answer (score 2):

have you tried resetting your settings?

TOOLS>IMPORT AND EXPORT>RESET ALL SETTINGS

Comment: no not really, i just tried to install 2013 and it worked

Answer (score 1):

It's called the Navigation bar. You can turn it on and off under Tools -> Options -> Text Editor. You find this option under the "General" tab of your language of choice (or, you can do it for "All Languages").