# How do I restore the default VS toolbar configuration?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, ide, defaults, uidefaults

**How do I restore the default VS toolbar configuration?**

By that, I mean:

- the set and location of enabled toolbars
- the set and order of items on each toolbar

**I know how to reset the set and order of items on a given toolbar**, so if I knew which are the default-enabled toolbars (and their location) then I would be able to enable and reset each of them one by one.

I don't want to [reset all VS settings](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33435691/122687).

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Tools > Import and Export Settings... > Import selected environment settings >

---

**Choose a Collection of Settings to Import**

Default Settings > Visual C# (or whatever language)

---

**Which settings do you want to import?**

Uncheck All Settings (everything is unchecked)

Check General Settings > Menu and Command Bar Customizations (only this!)